# What am I doing wrong with this post request?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I'm trying to authenticate with a web to get a valid token to implement a pay button.
I have this code in PHP:

```
$url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token';



$fields = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => $marketplace_client_id,
    'client_secret' => $marketplace_client_secret,
    'code' => $authorization_code,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
);

//al this variables are strings


$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($fields),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);

var_dump($context);

echo "<br><br>";
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);

echo "<br><br>";

$response = (array) json_decode($result);

var_dump($response);

echo "<br><br>";
echo $response["access_token"];
```

This code is returning

```
resource(2) of type (stream-context) 

bool(false) 

array(0) { }
```

When I do the post request with Postman for Chrome

I received at least

```
{
    "message": "Error validating grant. Your authorization code or refresh token may be expired or it was already used.",
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "status": 400,
    "cause": []
}
```

Sometimes I receive a success message.

I've read a lot of tutorials and it seems so simple I don't know what I'm missing. At least I would like to receive the error json so I can correct the problem in the input data but I don't even get this. Another rare thing is that the authorization_code expires at first use and everytime I run this code it expires so the server may be receiving my post request but I'm not getting the return message. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not a problem of my code. MercadoLibre (the site I've been sending the post request) only receives POST request vía cURL.

So I replaced my code with this one:

```
public function doPost($fields, $url) {

    $heads = array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    // build the post data following the api needs
    $posts = http_build_query($fields);

    // change the curl method following the api needs
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => '1',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $heads,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 'false',
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $posts,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3
    );
    // do a curl call
    $call = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($call, $options);
    // execute the curl call
    $response = curl_exec($call);
    // get the curl status
    //$status = curl_getinfo($call);
    // close the call
    curl_close($call);
    // transform the json in array
    $response = (array) json_decode($response);
    return $response;
}
```

And everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 3
```

is not working any more replace it with the new version of the SDK